# Compare the values of two arrays how has the same key and length

Tags: php, arrays

I want to compare the values of two arrays that have the **same key** (The activity) and have the same length.

**Arrays**

```
$anna_array = array("soccer" => "10", "basketball" => "20", "atletics" => "40");
$john_array = array("soccer" => "15", "basketball" => "15", "atletics" => "45");
```

I want to have something like:

```
<?php
if ($anna_array['soccer'] > $john_array['soccer']){
    $points = "1";
} else {
    $points = "0";
}
?>
```

Then I will use $points in the results:

```
<?php
foreach ($anna_array as $x => $x_value) {
$speler1_prestaties = "<span class=\"white bold\">".str_pad($count1++, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT)."</span> ".$x.": 
<span class=\"orange\">".$x_value." "(".$points .")></span><br />";     
echo $player1_info;
?>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You already compare the two array with the same key. What you want to do? What's the expected output?

Comment: Hi Federico, this is something like a game results. In the soccer game has Anna 10 goals and John 15 goals. So Anna get 1 point and John 0 points.

The output should be like: Anna(Soccer) 1  vs John(Soccer) 0.

Comment: and you want do that also for `basketball` and `atletics`?

Comment: @Fedrico. Yes. With array_intersect_key I managed to have two arrays with the same key and length.

Comment: what if there is a tie?

Comment: @Fredrico: if we have tie then 0 point for both.

Comment: so, in this case should be `Anna(Soccer) 0 vs John(Soccer) 1`, `Anna(basketball) 1 vs John(basketball) 0`, `Anna(atletics) 0 vs John(atletics) 1`, is that right?

Comment: @Fedrico. Yes. Exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can retrieve the common keys first applying `array_intersect_key` and then `array_keys`.

```
$common_sports = array_keys(array_intersect_key($anna_array, $john_array));
```

Then you can use `array_fill_keys` to fill an array with the same keys find above

```
$points_anna_array = $points_john_array = array_fill_keys($common_sports, 0);
```

The array here generated is:

```
 array(3) {
  ["soccer"]=>
  int(0)
  ["basketball"]=>
  int(0)
  ["atletics"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

Now you can compare the activity of anna and john

```
foreach ($common_sports as $common_sport) {
    if ($anna_array[$common_sport] > $john_array[$common_sport]) {
        $points_anna_array[$common_sport]++;
    } else if ($anna_array[$common_sport] < $john_array[$common_sport]) {
        $points_john_array[$common_sport]++;
    }
}
```

At this point `$points_anna_array`'s value would be this:

```
array(3) {
  ["soccer"]=>
  int(0)
  ["basketball"]=>
  int(1)
  ["atletics"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

and `$points_john_array` value:

```
array(3) {
  ["soccer"]=>
  int(1)
  ["basketball"]=>
  int(0)
  ["atletics"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

So:

```
foreach ($common_sports as $common_sport) {
    echo sprintf(
       'Anna(%s) %d vs John(%s) %d'."\n",
       $common_sport, $points_anna_array[$common_sport],
       $common_sport, $points_john_array[$common_sport]
    );
}
```

This will output:

```
Anna(soccer) 0 vs John(soccer) 1
Anna(basketball) 1 vs John(basketball) 0
Anna(atletics) 0 vs John(atletics) 1
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/CU24b).

To get the total score, you can use `array_sum`.

```
echo "John's total score: ", array_sum($points_john_array);
echo "Anna's total score: ", array_sum($points_anna_array);
```

Comment: @Thank you very much Federico:) This is exactly what I want.

Comment: @AnnaZina, I've added an example to get the total score from the arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a foreach and compare via keys:

```
foreach($anna as $key => $val){
    if(array_key_exists($key, $john)){
         if($val > $john[$key]){
             $points["john"] += 1;
         } else {
             $points["anna"] += 1;
         }
    }
}
```

I hope that I have understood your problem correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much. Frederico gave me exactly what I want. I will also use your code to get the total results. It works perfect:)